# .htaccess rewrite urls if multiple conditions are met

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite urls if a few conditions are met and an if/else statement in .htaccess

If the

- REQUEST_URI is empty or '/'
- SERVER_NAME doesn't contain the word 'sam'
- SERVER_PORT is 443.

Then prepend www. to the URL and append /website to the end of the URL.

Else if the

- REQUEST_URI is not empty or not '/'
- SERVER_NAME doesn't contain the word 'sam'
- SERVER_PORT is 443.

Then prepend www. to the URL.

Here's what I have so far but I'm unsure if this is the correct order and even if it's correct as it's not working for me, no redirect takes place.

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} == '/' || %{REQUEST_URI} == ''">
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} !sam
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
    RewriteRule .* https://www.%{SERVER_NAME}/website [R=301,L]
</If>
<Else>
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} !^sam
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
    RewriteRule .* https://www.%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</Else>
```

Comment: Without knowing the context, your second rule will more than likely create an infinite redirect loop. Also, are you using `SERVER_NAME` on purpose or is it `HTTP_HOST` that you want to use, actually ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use, without other test:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} !sam
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
RewriteRule ^$ https://www.%{SERVER_NAME}/website [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} !sam
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
RewriteRule ^.+$ https://www.%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: And here comes the infinite loop with second rule... Oops

Comment: @JustinIurman Not if the server is not the same or not with port 443... it's not part of the question, and there is not enough information

Comment: `Not if the server is not the same or not with port 443` -> will always be the case since the rule does not touch anything related. Anyway, agree with the rest. OP should review his scheme. Moreover, I suspect OP is mixing `SERVER_NAME` with `HTTP_HOST`

Comment: You can not know if DNS or configuration redirects www to another site

Comment: True. But as is, without more information, it's a bit tricky/dangerous to propose such a rule